# When using React, is there a best practice for handling sortBy change?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say, if there is a dropdown list to select which field to sort by.

Suppose we already have `data` as in:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

1. One way to handle this can be, to use in

```
const handleChange = (ev) => {

}
```

so that when the dropdown list selection is changed, the `data` is sorted accordingly.

2. Another way is that, we can use

```
useEffect(() => {

}, [data, sortBy]);
```

so that `sortBy` is a state, and changing that will cause the `useEffect` to run and reorder `data`.

Would approach 1 above be too "imperative" that doesn't go with React's declarative style?  I can see approach 2 above more like putting the imperative logic into the `useEffect()`, and let the rest of the code be declarative, which may be React's best practice?

P.S. Since writing this, I have two more options:

3. In either the handleChange or useEffect method above, sort the data and put it into another state, which is `sortedData`, so there is `const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState([]);` and I do a `setSortedData(newSortedData);`
4. Don't use (1) to (3) above. Use a

```
const sortedData = useMemo( function() { }, [data, sortBy]);
```

to get the `sortedData` and use it to render in the `return` part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Your sorted data is state that can be directly derived from other state (the items and the sort order), so [the most declarative hook is `useMemo`](http://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo):

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState(...);
const sortedData = useMemo(() => doSorting(data, sortBy), [data, sortBy]);
// ...
```

Comment: I get it... so you are using a `sortedData`, which is not a state, and say that it is the resultant of what `data` and `sortBy` produce.  Then using React this way is like spotting what the resultant and what dependencies constantly, isn't it? (I suppose this can be a best practice). Alternatively, would you make `sortedData` a state also? (by using `useState()`)

Comment: Also, what if we just create a brand new `data` object, with the sorted data, and set it using `setData(newData)`. Is that also an equally good solution?

Comment: I wouldn't make `sortedData` state, because it doesn't need to be state. You'd need to use an effect to call `setData`, so you'd be back to square one.

Comment: no, I mean, not using `sortedData`, but just create a new `data` and sort it, and set it as the new data, using `setData(newData)`

Comment: Then you'd have to keep those in sync somehow - and that somehow tends to be either `useEffect` or doing it manually.

Comment: @StefanieGauss maybe the react docs section "[you-might-not-need-an-effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)" will clarify things up for you.

Comment: @Aleksandar I think you are referring to: You don’t need Effects to transform data for rendering. For example, let’s say you want to filter a list before displaying it. You might feel tempted to write an Effect that updates a state variable when the list changes. However, this is inefficient. When you update the state, React will first call your component functions to calculate what should be on the screen. Then React will “commit” these changes to the DOM, updating the screen. Then React will run your Effects. If your Effect also immediately updates the state, this restarts the whole process